# percentage display with condition

Tags: javascript

```
 // Initialize the variables
  var oldValue = parseFloat(previousClosing.innerText.replace(/,/g, ''));
  var newValue = parseFloat(toggleIndexData.innerText.replace(/,/g, ''));

  // Calculate and display the percentage change
  var difference = newValue - oldValue;
  var percentageChange = (difference / oldValue) * 100;
  percentage.innerText =
    percentageChange.toString().includes('.00000')
      ? percentageChange.toFixed(2) + '%'
      : percentageChange.toString().includes('.0000')
      ? percentageChange.toFixed(6) + '%'
      : percentageChange.toString().includes('.000')
      ? percentageChange.toFixed(5) + '%'
      : percentageChange.toString().includes('.00')
      ? percentageChange.toFixed(4) + '%'
      : percentageChange.toString().includes('.0')
      ? percentageChange.toFixed(3) + '%'
      : percentageChange.toFixed(2) + '%';
```

I want to try to do same Result with last digit in Decimal

like example : 38,790.43 and 38,714.77 percentage is 0.20% only if we use two decimal
but if we switch to 3 decimal then percentage is 0.195%

**Condition:1** : if single zero '0' found in the decimal digit in the decimal value change to 3 decimal,

**Condition:2** : if two zero '00' found in the last digit in the decimal value change to 2 decimal,

**Condition: main** : if zero '0' Not found in the two Decimal value then stay with 2 Decimal.

i want to add this condition to my script

can anyone help me ? I am New

I am Look for this Type result.

`01. 0.20%      => 0.195%` 
`02.  0.200%    => 0.20%`

thank in advance

Comment: What if it is 0.198? When exactly you want 2 or 3 decimals? What is the rule?

Comment: i means to say : if 0 found in the last decimal then convert to 3 decimal, if in the 3 decimal have 2 zero like this 0.200% then return to 2 decimal

Comment: Does that mean that 153.80% should also become maybe 153.798%?

Comment: yes, this is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate one more decimal digit, and then delete the final "0" if there is one.

I would isolate the logic for this formatting in a separate function. You can also avoid some code repetition by using a regular expression that matches the decimal zeroes, so you can detect how many there are of them.

Using this snippet you can try different values interactively:

```js
const [previousClosing, toggleIndexData, percentage] = document.querySelectorAll("div");

// The main logic for formatting the percentatge is here:
function format(val) {
    if (Number.isNaN(val)) return ""; // Protect against bad input
    // Solve precision issues
    val = +val.toFixed(7);
    // Get the number of zeroes that precede the significant decimals
    let i = val.toFixed(7).match(/\.0*/)[0].length;
    // Determinal the number of desired decimals (standard)
    i = i > 5 ? 2 : i + 1;
    // Produce the two alternative representations
    const standard = val.toFixed(i);
    const extra = val.toFixed(i + 1);
    // Choose the one we want based on the final digit
    return standard.at(-1) == "0" && extra.at(-1) != "0" ? extra : standard;
}

function refresh() {
    // Initialize the variables
    var oldValue = parseFloat(previousClosing.innerText.replace(/,/g, ''));
    var newValue = parseFloat(toggleIndexData.innerText.replace(/,/g, ''));

    // Calculate and display the percentage change
    var difference = newValue - oldValue;
    var percentageChange = (difference / oldValue) * 100;
    percentage.innerText = format(percentageChange) + "%";
};
document.addEventListener("input", refresh);
refresh();
```

```css
div { display: inline-block; border: 1px solid; padding: 3px; width: 100px; }
```

```html
old value: <div contenteditable="true">100</div><br>
new value: <div contenteditable="true">100.195</div><br>
percentage: <div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but your code display 3 decimal when zero not found in the 2 decimal value,
i want to change 2 decimal to 3 decimal only if zero found , 
But
3 decimal Also Display 2 Zero Like 0.200% two zero in this condition change to 2 decimal.

Comment: Can you give more examples? For which input do you want to have a different outcome? My code does not produce 0.200%, but 0.20% in that case. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Condition 1 : 38,714.77 and 38,790.43 percentage is 0.20% in 2 Decimal , But if in 3 decimal then percentage is : 0.195%, if Perfentage display without Zero in 3 decimal convert to 3 decimal value.

Condition 2 : 10,000 and 20,000 percentage is 100.00% in 2 Decimal , two zero '00' found in this condition it's stay with 2 Decimal.


Condition main : if in the decimal percentage zero '0' not found then stay with 2 Decimal.

Comment: 38,790.43 and 387 percentage is = in two decimal 9923.37% but in 3 decimal it's look like this : 9923.367% in this condition not need to chnage 3 decimal because in two decimal Zero '0' Not Found

Comment: When I enter the first "condition", that you mention above, it displays 0.195%. When I enter the second example, the output is 100.00%. For the third example I have made an update to my answer. So there it now also displays 9923.37%. Is this what you need?